# Jenkins job to find merges/commits happened in GitHub Organisation

Tags: jenkins, github

I have a github organisation with 5000 repositories. I need to update/pull already cloned repositories when merge or commit happens in any of the repository. Tried with Jenkins, but it's polling only Repository but not Organisation. Configuring git hooks/webhooks is tedious job due to huge repo count. Please share your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Github Branch Source](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin) plugin. It will allow you to configure organization folder with all repositories. See the [documentation](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/plugins/github-branch-source/).